# Laravel Excel - Allowed memory exhausted even with WithChunkReading concern in place

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I'm trying to import an Excel file with 2 sheets both with 700 rows but memory runs out. I cannot increase memory limit since this is on a shared host.

Works fine on my Homestead though.

I'm not sure if the WithChunkReading is working or not. The code below is for importing the first sheet.

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date as ExcelDate;

class SummaryImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, WithBatchInserts
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $raw_date = $row['date_assigned_mmddyy'];

        try{
            $formatted = ($raw_date!='') ? Carbon::parse($raw_date)->toFormattedDateString() : '';

        }catch (\Exception $exception){

            try {
                $dt = ExcelDate::excelToDateTimeObject($raw_date);
                $formatted = Carbon::parse($dt)->toFormattedDateString();
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                Log::info($e->getMessage());
                $formatted = '';
            }

        }


        Card::updateOrCreate(
            ['card_number'=>$row['card']],
            [
                'customer_name'=> $row['customer_name'],
                'cs_number'=> $row['plate_or_cs'],
                'date_assigned'=> ($formatted == 'Jan 1, 1970') ? '': $formatted
            ]
        );


    }



    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

This one is for importing the second sheet.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Card;
use App\PointPeso;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class PointsPesoImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, WithBatchInserts
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        $card = Card::where('card_number','=', $row['card'])->get();

        if(count($card)){

            PointPeso::updateOrCreate(
                ['card_id'=>$card[0]->id],
                [
                    'total_points'=>$row['total_points']!=null ? $row['total_points']: '0',
                    'total_peso_value'=>$row['total_peso_value']!=null ? $row['total_peso_value']: '0'
                ]
            );

        }
    }


    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }

}
```

This is the Error Log:

```
[26-Aug-2019 05:34:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home1/synergj0/websites/poinstchecker/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php on line 1262
[26-Aug-2019 05:34:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home1/synergj0/websites/poinstchecker/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/AcceptHeaderItem.php on line 1
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class CardsImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Summary' => new SummaryImport,
            'Points Peso Monitoring' => new PointsPesoImport,
        ];
    }

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UploadRequest;
use App\Imports\CardsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;


class UploadsController extends Controller
{
    public function upload_form(){
        return view('uploader.uploader');
    }

    public function upload(UploadRequest $request){

        Excel::import(new CardsImport, $request->file('excel'));

        return redirect()->route('summary');
    }

}
```

Comment: This might be due to another piece of code. Are you looping through models somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any other codes which loops other model.

Comment: Could you show us the code where the `SummaryImport` is being created?

Comment: I tried to comment out Card::updateOrCreate(..., the code runs okay without actually writing to DB. Reading excel file fine. Storing to DB is another story.

I ended up contacting the hosting provider to adjust the memory limit & execution time just to make it work.

Comment: In this case you might have to queue reading docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html